# Грамотное использование try-catch  режимах Debug и Release

Tags: c#, .net

Хотелось бы различного поведения при Debug и Release вариантах программы. (Выполнялась обработка исключений в Release)
Сделал примерно так:

```
#if !DEBUG
try
{
#endif

#if !DEBUG    
}
catch
{}
#endif
```

Но меня не покидает мысль о неправильности данного решения с точки зрения феншуя. Подскажите, как можно реализовать данный функционал.

Comment: > не покидает мысль о неправильности данного решения с точки зрения феншуя

Вся эта идея не нужна. Выкиньте это все и делайте обработку исключений везде, где нужно. На всякий случай напомню про класс Debug.

Comment: Смысл этой конструкции - чтобы при возникновении исключения программа прекращала работу, а в релиз версии - выдавала пользователю сообщение об ошибке(а не просто падала).

Comment: @IsM
В таком виде в дебаге программа будет двать годные информативные сообщения, а вот в релизе исключение будет просто проглатываться, программа продолжит работу, находясь в поврежденном состоянии.

Comment: я писал с упрощением. Имел ввиду, например, такую конструкцию
 
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)    
    }

Comment: @IsM
Зачем пользователю на текст ошибок смотреть? Почему бы не логгировать вместе с этим? Лог можно попросить прислать, чтобы выследить беду по стектрейсу и предыстории.

Answer (score 1):

Замените эту конструкцию ассертами для дебаг-версии. А в catch нужно, как минимум, писать в лог, иначе вы - ССЗБ и пользователи вас проклянут =)